# Django admin override save behaviour

Tags: django, django-admin

Using the Django Admin I would like to have a 'confirmation box' when someone presses the save button in the admin interface i.e. you are trying to update "name or age or sex" to "foo or 23 or m".

Answer (score 1):

You could overwrite the get_form method in your model admin to add another check or the save() method to create a warning. You could also add an intermediate page (like the delete view does)...

i.e.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = patterns('',
            (r'^my_view/$', self.my_view)
        )
        return my_urls + urls

    def my_view(self, request):
        # custom view which should return an HttpResponse
        pass
```

Read more: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/os-django-admin/index.html?ca=drs

If you want a JavaScript method then I imagine you could just overwrite the admin view for that very easily and add a simple confirmation when save is click i.e.

```
 <a href="django url" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to save this item?');">Dave</a>
```

As the OP is very slim, with no code examples I cannot really help beyond this general answer.